# How can App Engine updates get put to the Google Cloud Storage, maven project is gone 0.4.4

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-storage

Android Studio before 0.4.4 had a Maven project that had utilities to upload and update App Engine code (including Cloud Storage endpoints).

In version 0.4.4 opening Maven Projects shows "no Maven projects"

How can I get App Engine code up to the cloud?

Comment: if you downvote, please make a comment about why you are downvoting so I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

So one way to do this would be from the command line using the maven command line tool (http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/).  Another option to say in the IDE would mean a little more work, but you might try loading up the Maven project in Intellij Community Edition and see if you can get it to work from there.  Android studio is moving away from supporting maven projects and the cloud tools are transitioning to using Gradle for their build.